# Windows 8 Lock screen won't unlock

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card

**Issue:**
I have this issue where after locking my PC (`Win+L`) I'm often unable to unlock it. When I come back to my pc, the screen is black. Activating the mouse or keyboard does not bring back the login screen. This does not happen every time, but quite often.

**Workaround:** I found a workaround to wake it up: I use another computer to remote desktop into my PC. Then I disconnect the remote desktop (without loging off). When come back to my PC, the login screen is there and I can login to restore my session.

**More info:**

- I've had this problem for a long time now (at least a year) running Windows 8. I few weeks ago I reformatted my computer with Windows 8.1. I still have the issue with this clean install.
- One other person in my team has the same issue. We have different computers but we have the same video card (SAPPHIRE Radeon HD 7770). However, several other people in the team have the same video card and don't have that problem.
- All sleep related powers saving features are disabled.

Comment: Are you sure the pc or monitor is not in some form of sleep? Eg, if you press the power button once, does it not bring you the screen you want? It sounds like you missed a power setting.

Comment: No, it's not black as in "turned off"; it's black as showing black. And sometimes it happens right after locking it.

Comment: Aha, I see. Dunno what it can be then. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before on Windows 8 & 10 installations, both upgraded from Windows 7, that had remote control software installed on them. In particular: remote control software that relies on a virtual video card driver to function properly.

Usually, reinstalling the complete software package (with reboots in between removal, installation and first use) would fix the driver issue.

Try checking the Windows Device Manager for any virtual video adapters. If there are any there, try reinstalling the software that the adapter belongs to. If that does not solve your problem, a second thing to look into is a driver from your video card manufacturer. Windows Update might have downloaded a WDM version that is slightly less perfect than the version that Sapphire provides.